# Border radius not showing on div

Tags: html, css

I have a simple 2 div I want to make round border of second div but its not working

My code

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div style="height: 100vh; background-color: #00aff0;" class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
  <div class="mh-100 row align-items-center justify-content-center" style="width: 90%; height: 100%;border-radius: 30px !important;overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 h-75" style="background-color: #b5ebff">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 h-75" style="background-color: white">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Running the snippet does give a border radius to the 2nd `div`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add css like as below
more detail for border radius: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp

```
border-radius: 50px;
```

and here is sample https://jsfiddle.net/6ekjbwzn/1/

```
<div style="height: 100vh; background-color: #00aff0;" class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
<div class="mh-100 row align-items-center justify-content-center" style="width: 90%; height: 100%;border-radius: 30px !important;overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 h-75" style="background-color: #b5ebff">
        

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 h-75" style="background-color: white;  border-radius: 50px;">

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your'e adding the `border-radius` to the row. This works fine, but the border radius doesnt show as the two child divs are not reaching the top/bottom corners. So the `border-radius` on the row *is working*, its just not visible tho.

Remove the `border-radius` from the row and move it onto the col(s).

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div style="height: 100vh; background-color: #00aff0;" class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
  <div class="mh-100 row align-items-center justify-content-center" style="width: 90%; height: 100%;overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 h-75" style="background-color: #b5ebff; border-radius: 30px;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 h-75" style="background-color: white; border-radius: 30px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this help, if you only want white div have border radius

```
 border-top-right-radius: 50px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
```

and you put border radius at row, that's not gonna work to white div

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div style="height: 100vh; background-color: #00aff0;" class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
  <div class="mh-100 row align-items-center justify-content-center" style="width: 90%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 h-75" style="background-color: #b5ebff">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 h-75" style="background-color: white; border-top-right-radius: 50px; border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a class `rounded-30` and assign it to the elements that should have a border. This gives you more flexibility. I would recommend avoiding inline styles and also the use of important.

```css
.rounded-30 {
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div style="height: 100vh; background-color: #00aff0;" class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
  
  <div class="mh-100 row align-items-center justify-content-center" style="width: 90%; height: 100%;overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="rounded-30 col-lg-6 col-md-6 h-75" style="background-color: #b5ebff;">
    </div>
    <div class="rounded-30 col-lg-6 col-md-6 h-75" style="background-color: white;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```